# Bulding an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have three hosts: `A`, `B`, `C`. `B` can connect to `C` through `ssh`, via port `221`. `A` cannot connect to `C` because it's behind a router, but can connect to `B` through `ssh`. What I need, is to connect from `A` to `C`.

The situation is summarized below:

`A -- p22 ---> B`  OK

`B -- p221---> C`  OK

`A -- p???---> C`  not working

I have tried many variations of `ssh` tunneling but looks like I don't get how tunneling works. Also, I have no root privileges on any of the hosts, therefore I cannot do port forwarding on port `22`. I am therefore not sure this tunneling can be done at all. If it can, however, I would appreciate the exact commands to run on each host so that I can finally ssh from A to C.

Answer (score 1):

While you could set up an explicit tunnel in this situation, it's much more convenient to use the `-J` option

```
ssh -J B -p 221 C
```

or the `ProxyJump` option explicitly

```
ssh -o ProxyJump=B -p 221 C
```

`ssh` will first connect to `B` for you (prompting for a password if necessary), then connect to `C` from `B`. From your point of view, you will have connected directly to `C`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `ssh -L local_port:another_host:destination_port user@host` is to say a/ start listening locally on `local_port` b/ connect to remote `host` (as usual), and once you're there, connect to that `another_host` and c/ forward everything you will receive locally to that another host's `destination_port`

so, I would try the following (from host A)

```
ssh -C -N -L 2222:C:221 user@B
```

then from another terminal

```
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost
```

I did not test the above.  Happy to dig deeper if required.

Here is the human readable explanation (hopefully) :

- starting from host A
- ssh, connect as `user` on host `B` (no port specified as 22 is the default)
- `-C` compress all content in transit in the tunnel
- `-N` says to not open a tty (interactive) session on host B
- `-L` says "once you're on B, start listening on this host (A) on port 2222 (as you are not root) and forward everything to C, port 221"

If you're using password authentication, it should work.  Certificate authentication would require a bit of additional configuration on B to correctly forward your certificate to C (which exact syntax I don't remember right now)